# Find multiple matching rows and then return the matching sub-row

Tags: excel

So I am having the following setup.

sheet `2023`:

[image: 2023-sheet]

sheet `2023-raw`:

[image: 2023-raw-sheet]

In the 2023-sheet I would now like to populate the cells with my working hours for that specific date. My way of thinking and trying to create an excel formula for this follows:

1. If matching week (vecka) exists in 2023-raw.
2. Then check if the current column name in 2023 sheet exists in the previous matched rows.
3. Make the calculations base of the return value in step 2.

So basically I have issues with getting the value from step 2. `MATCH` also only returns the first matching row? I would like to get a subset of all matching rows and then check again if the column name can be found in those rows.

Comment: Use FILTER to return multiple values

Comment: @user11222393 thanks, I have been able to filter out the correct row with the following: `=FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:'2023-raw'!G53,('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1),"h")`. However, is it possible to make addition and subtractions between columns from the resulting row?

Comment: @user11222393 post the following as a solution and I accept it. Go to the solution by your comment. `=INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 4) - INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 3) -  INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 5) -  INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP found a solution using a proposed `FILTER` formula in comment and asked to post it as an answer :

```
=INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 4) - INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 3) -  INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 5) -  INDEX(FILTER('2023-raw'!B2:G53, ('2023-raw'!B2:B53=A47) * ('2023-raw'!C2:C53=C1), "h"), , 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this `MATRIX

```
=MAKEARRAY(4,3,LAMBDA(r,c,
             SUMPRODUCT(tblData[Hours worked]*
                        (tblData[Week]=r)*
                        (tblData[Day]=INDEX(B8:D8,1,c)))
```

It will spill down - so that you can't use it in a table:

[image]

I simplified my example using a "hours worked" column - so you might add a new column to your table or you have to calculate the hours in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Just use SUMIFS to make calculus. SUMIFS will allow you to return a number based on criteria. If you are trying to calculate working ours (OUT minus IN) you can do it.

I made a fake dataset similar to yours:

[image]

Formula in cell B2 is:

```
=SUMIFS($O$2:$O$6;$L$2:$L$6;$A2;$M$2:$M$6;B$1)-SUMIFS($N$2:$N$6;$L$2:$L$6;$A2;$M$2:$M$6;B$1)
```

In case you need the output in decimal form, just multiply by 24, like the second example. Formula in cell B13 is:

```
=24*(SUMIFS($O$2:$O$6;$L$2:$L$6;$A2;$M$2:$M$6;B$1)-SUMIFS($N$2:$N$6;$L$2:$L$6;$A2;$M$2:$M$6;B$1))
```

In both cases just drag down and to right and the formula will work.

Please, notice this is based on the data you provided. If your working schedules sometimes go ahead 00:00 maybe you'll need to adjust a little bit.